# How to keep menu open?

Tags: drop-down-menu, widget, blogger

My  country/language menu is working ( pull down menu left side ), but I would like to keep it open ( indicating same language in menu bar , and also indicating same languages pages as choiced first ) 
This, while navigating between all pages in the selected  language. tks.
This code is inserted in: blogger, Widget , left side bar.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function select_type_fra()
   {
       document.getElementById(2).style.display = "block";
       document.getElementById(1).style.display = "none";
   }
   function select_type_eng()
   {
       document.getElementById(1).style.display = "block";
       document.getElementById(2).style.display = "none";
   }
   function select_type_vide()
   {
       document.getElementById(2).style.display = "none";
       document.getElementById(1).style.display = "none";
   }
    function affiche(value)
    {
   if (value=='choose')
   {
       select_type_vide()
   }
   else if(value=='fra')
   {
        select_type_fra()
   }
   else if(value=='eng')
   {
        select_type_eng()
   }
    }
</script>

<select onchange="affiche(this.value);">             
       <option  value="choose"> Language / Country </option>
       <option  value="fra"> Français </option>
       <option  value="eng"> english </option>   
</select>

<div id="1" style="display:none;">
<a href="#" >Page_1_English</a><br />
<a href="#" >Page_2_English</a><br />
</div>

<div id="2" style="display:none;">
<a href="#" >Page_1_French</a><br />
<a href="#" >Page_2_French</a><br />
</div>
```

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Some more context will help users answer your problem better.

Comment: yes i did had a look previously on help how to ask... what yould i add more on context?  ... i did mention: This code is inserted in: blogger, Widget , left side bar. tks

Comment: ...what should i add more...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<select class="select" multiple="multiple" onchange="affiche(this.value);">             
       <option  value="choose"> Language / Country </option>
       <option  value="fra"> Français </option>
       <option  value="eng"> english </option>   
</select>
```

It's not beautiful but It's what you want if I have understood correctly.